# crm command(cluster managment for pacemaker) not found in latest Centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, heartbeat, pacemaker, linux-ha

I have done such setup before, was no any issues. Now i can't do "crm configure" becuase no crm command availible in current package.

Am I missing something?
Maybe it replaced by other way/command?

```
[root@node1 src]# find / -name crm*|grep bin
/usr/sbin/crm_mon
/usr/sbin/crmadmin
/usr/sbin/crm_error
/usr/sbin/crm_shadow
/usr/sbin/crm_ticket
/usr/sbin/crm_failcount
/usr/sbin/crm_resource
/usr/sbin/crm_master
/usr/sbin/crm_diff
/usr/sbin/crm_attribute
/usr/sbin/crm_node
/usr/sbin/crm_simulate
/usr/sbin/crm_standby
/usr/sbin/crm_verify
/usr/sbin/crm_report
```

Comment: You may take a look at this:
[CRM - PCS equivalent commands](https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker/blob/master/doc/pcs-crmsh-quick-ref.md)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Red Hat has switched to use [`pcs`](http://oss.clusterlabs.org/pipermail/pacemaker/2012-June/014274.html) (Pacemaker Configuration System):

```
Name        : pcs
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 0.9.26
Release     : 10.el6
Size        : 248 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : Pacemaker Configuration System
URL         : http://github.com/feist/pcs
License     : GPLv2
Description : pcs is a corosync and pacemaker configuration tool.  It permits users to
            : easily view, modify and created pacemaker based clusters.
```

`crm` shell now has its own project: http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/crmsh/

You can install via [OpenSUSE repo](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ha-clustering/CentOS_CentOS-6/):

`wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d/ http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:ha-clustering:Stable/RedHat_RHEL-6/network:ha-clustering:Stable.repo`

`yum install crmsh.x86_64`

http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/ch03.html

Comment: thank you for you answer, but can you say HOW it expected to be configured "RHEL way" now?

Comment: BTW, i can confirm your answer works. But still need know what RHEL team think about "how to configure cluster"

Comment: downvoter: could you please leave a comment?
@arheops: updated my answer.

Comment: i can't find pcs package in Centos, and no such command availible..

Comment: `cat /etc/issue`? `yum repolist all`?

Comment: np. that was other centos windows. yes, i found that command. Will try find doc about how to use it(pacemaker doc for rhel6 still recomend use crm )

Comment: updated link to repository file: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ha-clustering:/Stable/CentOS_CentOS-6/network:ha-clustering:Stable.repo

Answer (score 2):

that repository also can not use anymore
use this one...
i just find a new one and it works now.
until 2013.8.9

```
wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d/ http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ha-clustering/CentOS_CentOS-6/network:ha-clustering.repo
```

cannot use anymore 2013.8.8 find another one

```
http://ftp.belnet.be/ftp.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ha-clustering/
#rpm –ivh pssh-2.3.1-15.1.x86_64.rpm
#yum install -y python-dateutil  redhat-rpm-config
#rpm –ivh crmsh-1.2.5-55.8.x86_64.rpm
```